# How to get text from many span in BeautifulSoup without class

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some information from a website that has the following html:

```
[<div _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" class="ng-star-inserted" fxlayout="row wrap" fxlayoutalign="space-between center" style="flex-flow: row wrap; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; place-content: center space-between; align-items: center;"><div _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" class="ng-star-inserted" fxflex="25" fxflex.gt-xs="25" fxlayout="column" fxlayoutalign="start center" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; flex: 1 1 25%; place-content: center flex-start; align-items: center; max-width: 25%;"><mat-icon _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-9" aria-hidden="true" cdk-describedby-host="" class="mat-icon notranslate mat-tooltip-trigger mat-primary material-icons" color="primary" mattooltip="Área Privativa" role="img">square_foot</mat-icon><!-- --><span _ngcontent-bsq-c159="">89m²</span></div><!-- --><!-- --><div _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" class="ng-star-inserted" fxflex="25" fxflex.gt-xs="25" fxlayout="column" fxlayoutalign="center center" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; flex: 1 1 25%; place-content: center; align-items: center; max-width: 25%;"><mat-icon _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-10" aria-hidden="true" cdk-describedby-host="" class="mat-icon notranslate mat-tooltip-trigger mat-primary material-icons" color="primary" data-toggle="tooltip" mattooltip="Quartos" role="img"> local_hotel</mat-icon><!-- --><span _ngcontent-bsq-c159=""> 3 <span _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" class="ng-star-inserted"> (1 Suite)</span><!-- --></span></div><!-- --><!-- --><div _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" fxflex="25" fxflex.gt-xs="25" fxlayout="column" fxlayoutalign="center center" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; flex: 1 1 25%; place-content: center; align-items: center; max-width: 25%;"><mat-icon _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-7" aria-hidden="true" cdk-describedby-host="" class="mat-icon notranslate mat-tooltip-trigger mat-primary material-icons" color="primary" mattooltip="Banheiros" role="img">bathtub</mat-icon><!-- --><span _ngcontent-bsq-c159="">2 </span></div><div _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" fxflex="25" fxflex.gt-xs="25" fxlayout="column" fxlayoutalign="center center" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; flex: 1 1 25%; place-content: center; align-items: center; max-width: 25%;"><mat-icon _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-8" aria-hidden="true" cdk-describedby-host="" class="mat-icon notranslate mat-tooltip-trigger mat-primary material-icons" color="primary" mattooltip="Garagens" role="img">drive_eta</mat-icon><!-- --><span _ngcontent-bsq-c159="">1 </span></div></div>, <div _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" class="ng-star-inserted" fxflex="25" fxflex.gt-xs="25" fxlayout="column" fxlayoutalign="start center" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; flex: 1 1 25%; place-content: center flex-start; align-items: center; max-width: 25%;"><mat-icon _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-9" aria-hidden="true" cdk-describedby-host="" class="mat-icon notranslate mat-tooltip-trigger mat-primary material-icons" color="primary" mattooltip="Área Privativa" role="img">square_foot</mat-icon><!-- --><span _ngcontent-bsq-c159="">89m²</span></div>, <div _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" class="ng-star-inserted" fxflex="25" fxflex.gt-xs="25" fxlayout="column" fxlayoutalign="center center" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; flex: 1 1 25%; place-content: center; align-items: center; max-width: 25%;"><mat-icon _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-10" aria-hidden="true" cdk-describedby-host="" class="mat-icon notranslate mat-tooltip-trigger mat-primary material-icons" color="primary" data-toggle="tooltip" mattooltip="Quartos" role="img"> local_hotel</mat-icon><!-- --><span _ngcontent-bsq-c159=""> 3 <span _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" class="ng-star-inserted"> (1 Suite)</span><!-- --></span></div>, <span _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" class="ng-star-inserted"> (1 Suite)</span>, <h3 _ngcontent-bsq-c159="" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-3" cdk-describedby-host="" class="mat-tooltip-trigger primary-color ng-star-inserted" mattooltip="Venda" style="color: rgb(211, 47, 47);"><span _ngcontent-bsq-c159="">USD 1,325,000.00</span></h3>]
```

I need to get values as "89m²", "3 (1 suite)", "2", "1" and "USD 1,325,000.00"

Comment: Why are there square brackets please? It obviously isn't a valid list or html. Can you include the html as you actually are processing it. Including your current code and an url (is possible) would help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind doing some manual indicing on strings in a list, this approach is quite straightforward.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<html content here>" # clipped for displaying on stack overflow
mainsoup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

spans = mainsoup.find_all('span') # I noted that all your desired values are in spans
items = [span.text for span in spans] # only take the text within those spanse
results = [items[0], items[1], items[3], items[4], items[-1]] # manual matching

print(results)
```

*out*

> ['89m²', ' 3  (1 Suite)', '2 ', '1 ', 'USD 1,325,000.00']

Comment: I tried your solution but `"ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Comment: the html above comes from `result= line.findAll(class_='ng-star-inserted')`

Comment: Next time try to include more information. I've been able to find a possible typo that could lead to this issue. Are you certain you are using `[span.text for span in spans]`? I think you are using span**s**.text and not `span.text`. In this case you would encounter the error you posted.

Comment: please check here: `result= line.findAll(class_='ng-star-inserted')
    spans = result.find_all('span')  
    items = [span.text for span in spans]
    for item in items:
        print(item)`

Comment: You've changed the logic of the code. Your post includes the variable `box1` as data. Yet you've added my solution on another variable, namely `result = box1.findAll(class_='ng-star-inserted')`. Remove this rule and replace the rule below it with `spans = box1.find_all('span') `. Next time, please include this code in the question, this makes it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: I found the error... `box1[0].find_all('span')`. Thanks!